# How to change value in Excel drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column that uses values from predefined set (a drop-down list), implemented using *Data Validations*. Now **if I change some value in the list**, the drop down (when open) will immediately offer this new value. However, **the table will not auto-update itself**, meaning that some of the values in the column will be invalid until I fix them manually.

I have seen solutions based on macros / VBA but isn't there some clever way directly in the Excel UI?

Comment: Not using data validation.

Comment: @chuff I am willing to use some other approach if that works, Data Validations are not a requirement.

Comment: Sorry Borek but it isn't possible without a macro or vba. Data validation is about checking the data at entry time. You would need to trigger something to update the cells with that value.

Comment: @NickPerkins And isn't there an alternative approach to Data Validations? Some other way to create a drop down?

Comment: @Borek You could use a combobox control, but then that requires VBA as well.

Comment: @Borek I'm just wondering if my answer below has helped at all?

Comment: @NickPerkins It has, I have upvoted it. Will wait a little longer before I accept it as an answer as I've seen mentioned somewhere that my goal is somehow achievable without macros, so maybe someone will come and describe it.

Answer (score 2):

As i mentioned in the comments, the only way to do this would be with VBA.

Here is one option. I've added comments throughout the code. This assumes that you are using a named range for the validation list named "List" and that it is on the same sheet as the cells being validated.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim isect As Range
    Dim vOldValue As Variant, vNewValue As Variant


    Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Names("List").RefersToRange)
    If Not isect Is Nothing Then
        ' Get previous value of this cell
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Target
            vNewValue = .Value
            Application.Undo
            vOldValue = .Value
            .Value = vNewValue
        End With

        ' For every cell with validation
        For Each cell In Me.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
            With cell
                ' If it has list validation AND the validation formula matches AND the value is the old value
                If .Validation.Type = 3 And .Validation.Formula1 = "=List" And .Value = vOldValue Then
                    ' Change the cell value
                    cell.Value = vNewValue
                End If
            End With
        Next cell
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You can also download the [example spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qytu0u6bp74zih1/Updated%20List%20Validated%20Cells%20on%20List%20Change.xlsm) I put together to test this out. (Contains macros!)

Comment: Could you provide that Dropbox link again?

Answer (score 0):

> but isn't there some clever way directly in the Excel UI?

I think I know one - at least it seems to meet all your requests:

1. You need to set **dynamically changing Named Region** as a source for Data Validation. This may be achieved using `OFFSET` function. Assuming you have the list of values for drop-down box in Column A of `Sheet1` (name matters only for formula), cell `A1` has header e.g. `List of values`, and values are placed starting `A2` and below, you should do the following: go Ribbon `Formulas > Name Manager`, create new Region (let's call it `Items`) and set its region NOT pointing to the cells, but using the following formula instead: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2;0;0;COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1;1)`.
2. Set **Data Validation** rules: instead of pointing to cells range for List, type `=Items` - thus your Named region will be used as list items source.
3. As a result of the above, you'll receive truly dynamic list which meets all your reqs: you may freely change / add items to column A, and these changes will be immediately reflected in dropdown the next time you use it. At the same time, old values will remain intact.

I use this solution for about 2 years in my work. Hope you'll find it useful as well!

P.S. here is the actual sample file: [Dynamic Dropdown](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqb3lpqftl8hh2s/Dynamic%20Dropdown.xlsx)

Comment: Oh, I think I misread the input - it seems that you need changed values being updated in the table as soon as you change them. My solution offers dynamic list, but old values will remain unchanged. Sorry for the confusion.