# Excel 2010: dynamic update of drop down list based upon datasource validation worksheet changes

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros, events

I have one worksheet for setting up the data sources of multiple data validation lists.
in other words, I'm using this worksheet to provide drop down lists to multiple other worksheets.

I need to dynamically update all worksheets upon any of a single or several changes on the data source worksheet. I may understand this should come with event macro over the entire workbook.

My question is how to achieve this keeping the "OFFSET" formula across the whole workbook ?

Thx

---

To support my question, I put the piece of code that I'm trying to get it working :

Provided the following informations :

- I'm using such a formula for a pseudo dynamic update of the drop down
  lists, for example :

=OFFSET(MyDataSourceSheet!$O$2;0;0;COUNTA(MyDataSourceSheet!O:O)-1)

- I looked into the [pearson book event chapter](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) but I'm too noob
  for this.
- I understand [this macro](https://superuser.com/a/532434/69050) and implemented it
  successfully as a test with the drop down list on the same worksheet
  as the data source. My point is that I don't know how to deploy this
  over a complete workbook.

Macro related to the datasource worksheet :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Macro to update all worksheets with drop down list referenced upon
' this data source worksheet, base on ref names

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim isect As Range
    Dim vOldValue As Variant, vNewValue As Variant

    Dim dvLists(1 To 6) As String 'data validation area
    Dim OneValidationListName As Variant

    dvLists(1) = "mylist1"
    dvLists(2) = "mylist2"
    dvLists(3) = "mylist3"
    dvLists(4) = "mylist4"
    dvLists(5) = "mylist5"
    dvLists(6) = "mylist6"

    On Error GoTo errorHandler

    For Each OneValidationListName In dvLists

        'Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Names("STEP").RefersToRange)
        Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Names(OneValidationListName).RefersToRange)

        ' If a change occured in the source data sheet
        If Not isect Is Nothing Then

            ' Prevent infinite loops
            Application.EnableEvents = False

            ' Get previous value of this cell
            With Target
                vNewValue = .Value
                Application.Undo
                vOldValue = .Value
                .Value = vNewValue
            End With

            ' LOCAL dropdown lists : For every cell with validation
            For Each cell In Me.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
                With cell
                    ' If it has list validation AND the validation formula matches AND the value is the old value
                    If .Validation.Type = 3 And .Validation.Formula1 = "=" & OneValidationListName And .Value = vOldValue Then

                        ' Debug
                        ' MsgBox "Address: " & Target.Address

                        ' Change the cell value
                         cell.Value = vNewValue



                    End If
                End With
            Next cell

            ' Call to other worksheets update macros
             Call Sheets(5).UpdateDropDownList(vOldValue, vNewValue)

            ' GoTo NowGetOut
            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If
     Next OneValidationListName


NowGetOut:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

errorHandler:
    MsgBox "Err " & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
    Resume NowGetOut


End Sub
```

Macro UpdateDropDownList related to the destination worksheet :

```
Sub UpdateDropDownList(Optional vOldValue As Variant, Optional vNewValue As Variant)

        ' Debug
        MsgBox "Received info for update : " & vNewValue

        ' For every cell with validation
        For Each cell In Me.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
            With cell
                ' If it has list validation AND the validation formula matches AND the value is the old value
                ' If .Validation.Type = 3 And .Value = vOldValue Then
                If .Validation.Type = 3 And .Value = vOldValue Then
                    ' Change the cell value
                    cell.Value = vNewValue
                End If
            End With
        Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it work now, based on the following setup :

One datasource worksheet with the worksheet change event setup as per the macro below. This macro calls the destination worksheet macro *UpdateDropDownList* with 2 arguments (old and new value) that are required for a dynamic update of the drop down lists.

Datasource worksheet macro (change event) :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Macro to update all worksheets with drop down list referenced upon
' this data source worksheet, base on ref names

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim isect As Range
    Dim vOldValue As Variant, vNewValue As Variant

    Dim dvLists(1 To 6) As String 'data validation area
    Dim OneValidationListName As Variant

    dvLists(1) = "myListName1"
    dvLists(2) = "myListName2"
    dvLists(3) = "myListName3"
    dvLists(4) = "myListName4"
    dvLists(5) = "myListName5"
    dvLists(6) = "myListName6"

    On Error GoTo errorHandler

    For Each OneValidationListName In dvLists

        Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Names(OneValidationListName).RefersToRange)

        ' If a change occured in the datasource worksheet
        If Not isect Is Nothing Then

            ' Prevent infinite loops
            Application.EnableEvents = False

            ' Get previous value of this cell
            With Target
                vNewValue = .Value
                Application.Undo
                vOldValue = .Value
                .Value = vNewValue
            End With

             ' Call to other worksheets update macros
             Call Sheets(5).UpdateDropDownList(vOldValue, vNewValue)

            ' GoTo NowGetOut
            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If
    Next OneValidationListName


NowGetOut:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

errorHandler:
    MsgBox "Format Err " & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
    Resume NowGetOut


End Sub
```

Destination worksheet macro :

```
Sub UpdateDropDownList(Optional vOldValue As Variant, Optional vNewValue As Variant)

On Error GoTo errorHandler

        ' Debug
        ' MsgBox "Received info for update : " & vNewValue

        ' For every cell with validation
        For Each cell In Me.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
            With cell
                ' If it has list validation AND the validation formula matches AND the value is the old value
                If .Validation.Type = 3 And .Value = vOldValue Then
                    ' Change the cell value
                    cell.Value = vNewValue
                End If
            End With
        Next cell

Exit Sub

errorHandler:
    MsgBox "Saisie Err : " & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
End Sub
```